# Android Currency to float

Tags: android, currency

Hello I have data stored in SQLite db in float format.
That data I view them in my TextView with NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
But now when I pass those values ​​to change them should convert back to float.
How do I prevent exceptions?

`extras.putString("sale", tv_sale.getText().toString());`

Comment: Do **not** use a float to store currency! It is not precise, and as such you will encounter issues with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the currency as a BigDecimal in Java and as then as a String.

You can use the toPlainString() method.

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal();
String s = b.toPlainString();
```

Then when you pull it from the database you can create a new BigDecimal.

BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal(String s)

Believe it or not SQLite 3.0 stores all data types as strings even if you say it should be an Integer. [See here](http://www.sqlite.org/version3.html) and scroll down to the "Manifest Typing and BLOB Support" section. It talks about how it will let you store strings in columns of other types.